# Reading an .xls file in python (using pandas read_excel)

Tags: python, pandas, xls

So I have an `.xls` file which I am able to open with Excel and also with Notepad (can see the numbers along with some other text) but I cannot read the file using pandas module.

```
df = pd.read_excel(r'"R:\Project\Projects\429 - Buchner Höhe\Analysis Data\scada\20171101.xls"',parse_dates=[[0,1,2,3]])
```

The error which pops up is as follows:

> XLRDError: Unsupported format, or corrupt file: Expected BOF record;
>   found b'\x03\x11\x0b\x02 \x01\x00\x00'

I tried renaming the file to `.xlsx` using `os.rename`, it still does not work.

Comment: Can you please post the code you wrote? You're more likely to get help if your question provides a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: df=pd.read_excel(r'"R:\Project\Projects\429 - Buchner Höhe\Analysis Data\scada\20171101.xls"',parse_dates=[[0,1,2,3]])

Comment: MS Excel is able to open a XLS/XLSX file even it this last has few error.
Maybe Pandas don't...

Comment: Maybe duplicate with - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16504975/error-unsupported-format-or-corrupt-file-expected-bof-record - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9623029/python-xlrd-unsupported-format-or-corrupt-file - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45700658/pandas-read-excel-unsupported-format-or-corrupt-file-expected-bof-record

Comment: Yes i checked the post already. It did not help in solving. Therefore I posted here again

Comment: And i am reading a .xls file here with pandas which uses xlrd module and this error arises

Comment: Try installing the latest version of `xlrd`, e.g. `pip install xlrd --upgrade`

Comment: Yes I did that still I have the same error

Comment: It worked after i opened all the .xls files and saved them as .csv and then used pd.read_csv. Still the issue with reading .xls files remains unsolved

Answer (score 1):

It is quite likely the file was already a csv file--not an xls or xlsx, renamed through the file system, rather than an actual Excel format file. This is the error generated when you attempt to open a csv with xlrd.

The indicator that this is the case is you can open it with Notepad.