# Python - XLRDError: Unsupported format, or corrupt file: Expected BOF record

Tags: python, pandas, xlrd

I am trying to open an excel file which was given to me for my project, the excel file is the file that we get from a SAP system. But when I try opening it using `pandas` I am getting the following error:

> XLRDError: Unsupported format, or corrupt file: Expected BOF record; found '\xff\xfe\r\x00\n\x00\r\x00'

The following is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
# To open an excel file
df = pd.ExcelFile('myexcel.xls').parse('Sheet1')
```

Comment: are you able to open the file in msexcel?

Comment: yes I am able to open it using msexcel, but not in pandas

Comment: Can you attach the XLS file in the question?

Comment: Hi Arpit, actually the data is bit confidential, all are medical data.

Answer (score 2):

Dont know whether it will work for you once it had worked for me, but anyway can you try the following:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from xlwt import Workbook
import io

filename = r'myexcel.xls'
# Opening the file using 'utf-16' encoding
file1 = io.open(filename, "r", encoding="utf-16")
data = file1.readlines()

# Creating a workbook object
xldoc = Workbook()
# Adding a sheet to the workbook object
sheet = xldoc.add_sheet("Sheet1", cell_overwrite_ok=True)
# Iterating and saving the data to sheet
for i, row in enumerate(data):
    # Two things are done here
    # Removeing the '\n' which comes while reading the file using io.open
    # Getting the values after splitting using '\t'
    for j, val in enumerate(row.replace('\n', '').split('\t')):
        sheet.write(i, j, val)

# Saving the file as an excel file
xldoc.save('myexcel.xls')
```

Comment: hi, I am getting the following error `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'xlwt'`

Comment: you need to install `xlwt` library .

Comment: can you try using `encoding='utf-16le'`

Comment: for some files it worked using `utf-16le`, and for others it worked using `utf-16`. Anyway thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had faced the same `xlrd.biffh.XLRDError: Unsupported format, or corrupt file: Expected BOF record;` error and solved it by writing an XML to XLSX converter. You can call `pd.ExcelFile('myexcel.xlsx')` after the convertion. The reason is that actually, pandas uses xlrd for reading Excel files and xlrd does not support XML Spreadsheet (*.xml) i.e. NOT in XLS or XLSX format.

```py
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def convert_to_xlsx():
    with open('sample.xls') as xml_file:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(xml_file.read(), 'xml')
        writer = pd.ExcelWriter('sample.xlsx')
        for sheet in soup.findAll('Worksheet'):
            sheet_as_list = []
            for row in sheet.findAll('Row'):
                sheet_as_list.append([cell.Data.text if cell.Data else '' for cell in row.findAll('Cell')])
            pd.DataFrame(sheet_as_list).to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet.attrs['ss:Name'], index=False, header=False)

        writer.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was applying this advice:

[How to cope with an XLRDError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45700658/pandas-read-excel-unsupported-format-or-corrupt-file-expected-bof-record)

There you also find a suitable explanation that was appropiated for me. It says that the problem was a file format not correctly saved.  When I opened the xls file, it offered to save it as html.I saved it a ".xlsx" and solved the problem