# Pandas, skip empty columns in xslx

Tags: python, excel, pandas

Im trying to find if a .xlsx file contains a @.
I have used pandas, which work great, unless if the excel sheet have the first column empty, then it fails.. any ideas how to rewrite the code to handle/skip empty columns?

the code:

```
df = pandas.read_excel(open(path,'rb'), sheetname=0)
out = 'False'
for col in df.columns:
    if df[col].str.contains('@').any():
        out = 'True'
        break
```

This is the error i'm getting:

```
    df = pandas.read_excel(open(path,'rb'), sheetname=0)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/excel.py", line 203, in read_excel
    io = ExcelFile(io, engine=engine)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/excel.py", line 258, in __init__
    self.book = xlrd.open_workbook(file_contents=data)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/xlrd/__init__.py", line 162, in open_workbook
    ragged_rows=ragged_rows,
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/xlrd/book.py", line 91, in open_workbook_xls
    biff_version = bk.getbof(XL_WORKBOOK_GLOBALS)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/xlrd/book.py", line 1271, in getbof
    bof_error('Expected BOF record; found %r' % self.mem[savpos:savpos+8])
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/xlrd/book.py", line 1265, in bof_error
    raise XLRDError('Unsupported format, or corrupt file: ' + msg)
xlrd.biffh.XLRDError: Unsupported format, or corrupt file: Expected BOF record; found b'\x17Microso'
```

Comment: I guess that the Excel you are working with is already opened, before letting the Python script run? Check this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16504975/error-unsupported-format-or-corrupt-file-expected-bof-record

Comment: FYI - In general, whenever you are getting an error like this, the lowest line is the most important one, which is actually generating the error, the rest is just the stack of the error-handling

Comment: Thanks, that was excellent information :-)

Comment: Cant figure out the how to make the exception, if a user have the excel open.. it should just skip that file, or make out = 'Maybe'

Comment: See the first two answers here and build a similar function with Python -  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9373082/detect-whether-excel-workbook-is-already-open

Comment: Im on a mac, and when opening a file it automaticly makes a temp file called ~$ in the begining.. its this file sit tries to read but fails in :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check whether at least one cell **equals** to specific character/string:

```
def excel_has_str(filename, search='@'):
    return pd.read_excel(filename).astype(str).eq(search).any().any()
```

If you want to check whether at least one cell **contains** specific character/string:

```
def excel_contains_str(filename, search='@'):
    return pd.read_excel(filename) \
             .astype(str) \
             .apply(lambda x: x.str.contains(search)) \
             .any() \
             .any()
```

It'll automatically take care of empty strings and empty columns...

Comment: Thanks, do you have a fix for when its failes because the file is open? Getting the 'xlrd.biffh.XLRDError: Unsupported format' error

Comment: @RasmusBidstrup, does it work properly with closed excel file?

Comment: Yes, then all is fine

Comment: @RasmusBidstrup, try to file a bug by “xlrd” https://github.com/python-excel/xlrd/issues

Comment: Thanks I will try that

Answer (score 1):

[This might help](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16504975/6697020). As the link says, probably is an HTML file with xlsx extension or it is open already by Excel. 
Also you could try to load it this way and see what happens:

```
pd.read_excel(path_of_file, sheetname=0)
```