# Parse excel (.xlsx) from S3 using lambda python- aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I'm trying to parse an .xlsx file stored in s3 using lambda python. Stored it to /tmp/ and tried parsing with xlrd. I'm getting "BOF error".

Comment: Please share a minimal code sample that produces the issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: Unsupported format, or corrupt file: Expected BOF record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16504975/error-unsupported-format-or-corrupt-file-expected-bof-record)