# How to only import all excel files from a directory

Tags: python

I need to import all excel files in my directory, including sub directories, but I keep getting into an error message because there are other types of files in the same directory such as pdf and word. How do I my current code below to ignore all other types of files and only import excel files wit the xlsx extension.

```
for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(data_path):
    for file in files:
            df_file = pd.read_excel(subdir + '/' +file)
            df_file.set_index(df_file.columns[0], inplace=True)
        
            df_total = pd.concat([df_file, df_total], ignore_index=True)
```

I tried something like if file.endswith("xlsx"): but it didn't work.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by didn't work? What was the error while using `if file.endswith(".xlsx"): ` ?

Comment: @susenj I got this message:Unsupported format, or corrupt file: Expected BOF record; found b'\rAdminis'

Comment: this problem is answered already, there is nothing wrong with your code, it seems. Please check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16504975/error-unsupported-format-or-corrupt-file-expected-bof-record

Answer (score 2):

The problem you are struggling with has already an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20908018/import-multiple-excel-files-into-python-pandas-and-concatenate-them-into-one-dat).

You don't even have to use any additional module you just need the path of the directory where the excel files are and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an if statement to check if it endswith `.xlsx` (I know you said you've tried it but this one would work):

```py
for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(data_path):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".xlsx"): 
            df_file = pd.read_excel(subdir + '/' +file)
            df_file.set_index(df_file.columns[0], inplace=True)
        
            df_total = pd.concat([df_file, df_total], ignore_index=True)
```