# python / pandas - Import last modified .xlsx file from a directory

Tags: python, excel, glob, xlrd, last-modified

I have a folder in dropbox with path:

```
C:\Users\Sophocles PC\Dropbox\RGS Delivery\Impact Coefficients\Consumer Discretionary\CD_LG_Apparel_Accessories_Luxury_Goods\Data\CD_LG_DataOutputs
```

and I want to **import the last modified** `.xlsx` file. I use the code:

```
list_of_files = glob.glob(r'C:\Users\Sophocles PC\Dropbox\RGS Delivery\Impact Coefficients\Consumer Discretionary\CD_LG_Apparel_Accessories_Luxury_Goods\Data\CD_LG_DataOutputs/*') 
latest_file = max(list_of_files, key=os.path.getctime)
```

the `latest_file` , prints:

```
C:\Users\Sophocles PC\Dropbox\RGS Delivery\Impact Coefficients\Consumer Discretionary\CD_LG_Apparel_Accessories_Luxury_Goods\Data\CD_LG_DataOutputs\~$CD_LG_Results - 2020-11-27 - mean - v2.xlsx
```

which is in fact the latest file, and therefore the file I want to import. **However**, when I try to import the file:

```
x = pd.read_excel(latest_file)
```

I get the following error:  `XLRDError: Unsupported format, or corrupt file: Expected BOF record; found b'\x0cSophocl'`

I don't know how to fix the error, but I also think that fixing this should be fairly straight forward. Any help on this will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Possibly related to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16504975/error-unsupported-format-or-corrupt-file-expected-bof-record. Does read_csv work?

Comment: i think the file is a temp file, ~$ this indicates it. close the file restart the PC and Try again, ~$ Should not come. it is temp file created when spreadsheet is open

Comment: may be you have to delete that temp file in the dropbox

Comment: Thanks @VigneshRajendran, I think that's what the issue. I was able to resolve it with using: ```x = pd.read_excel(f"{latest_file}".replace('~$',''),sheet_name=2)```

Comment: Happy about that @sophods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question was solved after removing `~$` (temp-file) using the code below:

```
x = pd.read_excel(f"{latest_file}".replace('~$',''),sheet_name=2)
```

Thanks.