# Excel file not supported by pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas

Unsupported format, or corrupt file: Expected BOF record; found b'<H1 alig'
I get this error when I try to connect by excel file with pandas.

Comment: What happens when you save a sheet from the file as `.csv` and read it into pandas?

Comment: Have a look at this thread. [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16504975/error-unsupported-format-or-corrupt-file-expected-bof-record)

Comment: It would be helpful if you show us your code and explain in more detail. Have you seen this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16504975/error-unsupported-format-or-corrupt-file-expected-bof-record?

Answer (score 0):

Answer:

```py
import pandas as pd
data=pd.read_html('File_name.xls')[0]
data.to_excel('NewFile_name.xlsx')
```