# Parsing binary data inside .xls file

Tags: python, excel, pandas, xls, xlrd

I have multiple files with xls extension, but when I try to read the data inside any of these excel files using xlrd it throws this error:

xlrd.biffh.XLRDError: Unsupported format, or corrupt file: Expected BOF record; found b'Cycle ID'

*Cycle ID is part of the content written in the first cell of the excel file.

Is there a way to rewrite these excel files but with the data in string format so I can read it and use it later?

This is is the result of cat myfile.xls | head:

Cycle ID: MARQUES_220443

Subject information

Subject ID:

Last name:      First name:

DOB:

Features:

Karyotype:

Consultant:

Comment: can you show what the result of `cat myfile.xls | head` gives you (assuming you are on *nix)?

Comment: Also, have you consulted: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16504975/error-unsupported-format-or-corrupt-file-expected-bof-record yet?

Comment: This is is the result of cat myfile.xls | head:

Cycle ID: MARQUES_220443
Subject information

Subject ID:
Last name:      First name:
DOB:
Features:
Karyotype:

Comment: *Why would you post that in a comment??* Post it in the question itself as formatted text. Where people can actually read it

Comment: In any case, that looks like a simple text file (perhaps TSV?), not an xls file