# Python - XLRD cannot open XLS files due to Unsupported format, or corrupt file; Expected BOF record

Tags: python, pandas, format, xls, xlrd

I have a folder full of XLS files that I am attempting to read into a Pandas data frame.

My code:

```
daily_postings_folder = '//DAILY POSTINGS - MAY23/'

daily_postings_list = glob.glob(os.path.join(daily_postings_folder, "*.xls"))

daily_postings_df = pd.concat((pd.read_excel(g, engine='xlrd', header=None) for g in daily_postings_list), ignore_index=True)
daily_postings_df.head()
```

The error I'm getting is this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "z:\Trade Reconciliation\Testing\Python_Testing\daily_trade_rec.v3(DEV).py", line 20, in <module>
    daily_postings_df = pd.concat((pd.read_excel(g, engine='xlrd', header=None) for g in daily_postings_list), ignore_index=True)
  File "C:\Users\tac6328\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py", line 311, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\tac6328\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\concat.py", line 347, in concat
    op = _Concatenator(
  File "C:\Users\tac6328\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\concat.py", line 401, in __init__
    objs = list(objs)
  File "z:\Trade Reconciliation\Testing\Python_Testing\daily_trade_rec.v3(DEV).py", line 20, in <genexpr>
    daily_postings_df = pd.concat((pd.read_excel(g, engine='xlrd', header=None) for g in daily_postings_list), ignore_index=True)
  File "C:\Users\tac6328\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py", line 311, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\tac6328\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py", line 457, in read_excel
    io = ExcelFile(io, storage_options=storage_options, engine=engine)
  File "C:\Users\tac6328\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py", line 1419, in __init__
    self._reader = self._engines[engine](self._io, storage_options=storage_options)
  File "C:\Users\tac6328\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_xlrd.py", line 25, in __init__
    super().__init__(filepath_or_buffer, storage_options=storage_options)
  File "C:\Users\tac6328\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py", line 518, in __init__
    self.book = self.load_workbook(self.handles.handle)
  File "C:\Users\tac6328\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_xlrd.py", line 38, in load_workbook
    return open_workbook(file_contents=data)
  File "C:\Users\tac6328\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xlrd\__init__.py", line 172, in open_workbook
    bk = open_workbook_xls(
  File "C:\Users\tac6328\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xlrd\book.py", line 79, in open_workbook_xls
    biff_version = bk.getbof(XL_WORKBOOK_GLOBALS)
  File "C:\Users\tac6328\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xlrd\book.py", line 1284, in getbof
    bof_error('Expected BOF record; found %r' % self.mem[savpos:savpos+8])
  File "C:\Users\tac6328\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xlrd\book.py", line 1278, in bof_error
    raise XLRDError('Unsupported format, or corrupt file: ' + msg)
xlrd.biffh.XLRDError: Unsupported format, or corrupt file: Expected BOF record; found b'\xef\xbb\xbf<?xml'
```

The files are all XLS files so not sure what the problem is here.

Comment: Have you tried opening all the xls files to determine if any are corrupt (ie., even Excel cannot open them?). Or narrowing this down to determine the actual file that is a problem?

Comment: All of the files open in Excel fine, they're in Compatibility Mode though, don't know if that makes a difference or not.

Comment: Is it one file that is the problem, or all of the files?

Comment: Could be any or all of them, I get this message when opening any of the files:

"The file format and extension of 'filename.xls' don't match. The file could be corrupted or unsafe. Unless you trust its source, don't open it. Do you want to open it anyway?" 

But then I click "Yes" and they open in Excel afterwards just fine.

Comment: Try the suggestions here: [error-unsupported-format-or-corrupt-file-expected-bof-record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16504975/error-unsupported-format-or-corrupt-file-expected-bof-record) ... one of them is that the file isn't really an xls file but a csv file (which Excel can open even though its not an actual xls format). Also encoding issues are a possibility as well.

Comment: Viewing the file in a text editor will tell you if its a csv file ...